# Using Injectable service from Directive and Component angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular2-services

I'm quite confused and need a small guide, I have a component class named `ItemsActionsDynamicComponent` which using an injecable service called ItemsActionsDynamicService that sending all of the HTTP requests.

Now i used another directive called JquiDialogLauncher, i'm trying to user the ItemsActionsDynamicService when confirmation button is pressed in order to send the HTTP req, while doing it i'm getting `Cannot read property 'postSyncItemFromSource' of undefined`

ItemsActionsDynamicComponent:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {ItemsActionsDynamicService} from "./item-actions-dynamic.service";
import {FadeInTop} from "../../../../shared/animations/fade-in-top.decorator";
import {ModalComponent} from "ng2-bs3-modal/components/modal";


declare var $: any;
@FadeInTop()
@Component({
    selector: 'items-actions-dynamic',
    templateUrl: './items-actions-dynamic.component.html',
    providers: [ItemsActionsDynamicService]
})
export class ItemsActionsDynamicComponent {


    constructor(... private _itemsActionsDynamicService: ItemsActionsDynamicService) {

    }

    ..


    syncItemDialogOptions = {
        autoOpen : false,
        width : 600,
        resizable : false,
        modal : true,
        closeText: '',
        title : "<div class='widget-header'><h4><i class='fa fa-warning'></i> Sync Item</h4></div>",
        buttons : [{
            html : "<i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>&nbsp; Ok",
            "class" : "btn btn-danger",
            click : function() {
                this._itemsActionsDynamicService.postSyncItemFromSource();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }, {
            html : "<i class='fa fa-times'></i>&nbsp; Cancel",
            "class" : "btn btn-default",
            click : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    };

    public syncItem() {
        console.log("syncItem")
        this._itemsActionsDynamicService.postSyncItemFromSource(itemUUID);
    }

}
```

items-actions-dynamic.component.html :

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"  (click)="syncItem()">Test Sync Item</button>

<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"  saJquiDialogLauncher="#sync-item-dialog">Sync Item</button>

<div id="sync-item-dialog" [saJquiDialog]="syncItemDialogOptions">
</div>
```

JquiDialogLauncher:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[saJquiDialogLauncher]'
})
export class JquiDialogLauncher {
  @Input() saJquiDialogLauncher: any;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(e) {
    $( this.saJquiDialogLauncher ).dialog( "open" );
  }

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

}
```

when clicking on Test Sync Item, everything is working well, when clicking on Sync Item im getting `cannot read property 'postSyncItemFromSource' of undefined`

In order to make Sync Item works, what shell i do? inject the ItemsActionsDynamicService into JquiDialogLauncher directive? if so how do i use the method then?

Comment: @echonax not really, went over it and seems like its slightly different, i need to pass the option into the directive from the component therefore the "this" trick with the local function var not working...

Comment: Makes no difference, the answers to the question @echonax pointed at explain what's going on here and how you fix it. In your `.btn.btn-danger` click handler, you're trying to use `this` for two separate things. You can't do that. Either use an arrow function and `$(e.target).close()` (being sure to accept the event parameter), or use `var component = this;` prior to the `syncItemDialogOptions =` line and then use `component._itemsActionsDynamicService.postSyncItemFromSource();`. Both of these, and several others, are covered in detail.